# The meaning of 美味しいクッキーで子供たちに大人気

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-で, renyōkei

> **Woman 1** 「アスタの作るクッキーは香りが豊かで、焼き始めるとスタリオンの子供たちが屋敷に集まってくるのよね」
>
> **アスタ** 「簡単に焼けるから、みんなに配る分もすぐに準備出来るからね」
>
> **Woman 2** 「うむ、領地の子供たちに美味しい物を振る舞うとは……さすが領主の義理息子だけはある」
>
> **Woman 1** 「感心しているけど、あんたは実の娘でしょうが」
>
> **Man 1** 「美味しいクッキーで子供たちに大人気か」

Now my question is about the last part 美味しいクッキーで子供たちに大人気, as I am completely stumped as to what it means. The possible interpretations that I can think of would be

1. It means that he makes delicious cookies and he is popular with the kids
2. He is popular with the kids due to his delicious cookies
3. His cookies are delicious and they are very popular with the kids.

Can anyone explain which of these is correct and why the others would be incorrect? (If none of the above are correct then please state what it means to you.)

Answer (score 2):

Methinks 2) is a good guess.

で in this case stands for "by", "with", "because of" or "due to".

Meanwhile I don't think 1) and 3) are particularly out-of-point.